# Only able to get single row in quote pdf, not multiple

Tags: visualforce, pdf, developer

I am trying to create a quote pdf based off the opportunity line items in Salesforce. So far I have only been able to generate a single row in the quote pdf and not multiple. When I try to add multiple products of the same type with different POL & POD, I get the following error: "Map key Ocean Freight FCL 20GP not found in map". How can I fix this to allow multiple rows.

I want it to look like the below image

[image: I want it to look like this]

Here is my visualforce page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="MultiQuotePDFController" renderAs="pdf" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
            <style type="text/css">
                @page{
                    size: A4 landscape;
                    margin:0.1in;
                } 

                body {
                    font-family: "sans-serif";
                    font-size: 10px;
                }

                .freight_quote_text {
                    font-size: 20px;
                    color: #c0c0c0;
                    float: right;
                }

                #theImage {
                    float: right;
                }

                .top_section {
                    display: table;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .top_sections {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                    font-size: 40px;
                    color: #ff7e23;
                }

                .left_align {
                    text-align: left;
                }

                .right_align {
                    text-align: right;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }

                .bottom_section {
                    width: 100%;
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 0px;
                }

                .terms_and_conditions {
                    font-size: 8px;
                }

                .list {
                    border-spacing: 0px;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-size: 9px;
                }

                .list th {
                    vertical-align: top;
                    font-weight: normal;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(IsError)}">
            <div class="top_section" style="">
                <div class="top_sections left_align">
                    <apex:outputtext value="{!OpportunityRecord.Account.Name}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="top_sections right_align">
                    <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.BeaconLogo}" width="230" height="50"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="freight_quote_text">
                Freight Quote
            </div>
                   
            <table class="details">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right; white-space: nowrap;">Quoted Date:</td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
                                <apex:param value="{!OpportunityRecord.Quoted_Date__c}" />
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    
                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <div style="border: 1px solid black">
                    <table class="list" style="table-layout:auto; width:100%; border: 1px solid black;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Pickup__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POL__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POD__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Dep_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Arr_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Delivery__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}"> </th>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits}" var="key">
                                    <th colspan="{!ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap[key]}" style="border-right: 1px solid black;">{!key}<br/>{!ProductNameToCurrencyMap[key]}</th>
                                </apex:repeat>
                                    <th colspan="5"> Totals<br/>{!OpportunityProductsList[0].quote_currency__c}</th>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Pickup__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Pickup</th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POL__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">POL</th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POD__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">POD</th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Dep_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Dep Airport</th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Arr_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Arr Airport</th>
                                <th style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Delivery__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none;')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Delivery</th>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits}" var="key">
                                    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="columnCount"/>
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits[key]}" var="item">
                                        <th style="{!IF(ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap[key]==columnCount, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', '')} border-bottom: 1px solid black;">{!item}</th>
                                        <apex:variable value="{!columnCount+1}" var="columnCount" />
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:repeat>
                                <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Single_Reference__c,true,false)}">
                                    <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"> </th>
                                </apex:outputText>
                                <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Single_Reference__c,false,true)}">
                                    <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="columnCount2"/>
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!OverallListOfUnits}" var="unit">
                                        <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">{!unit}</th>
                                        <apex:variable value="{!columnCount2+1}" var="columnCount2" />
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:outputText>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="i"/>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!ConvertedOpportunityProductsList}" var="item">
                                <tr style="background-color:{!IF(mod(i,2)==0, '#F3F3F3', '#FFFFFF')};">
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Pickup__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Pickup}</td>
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POL__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Starting_Point_Seaport_Name}</td>
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_POD__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Ending_Point_Seaport_Name}</td>
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Dep_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Starting_Point_Airport_Name}</td>
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Arr_Airport__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Ending_Point_Airport_Name}</td>
                                    <td style="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Display_Delivery__c, 'border-right: 1px solid black;', 'display:none')}">{!item.Delivery}</td>
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits}" var="key">
                                        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="columnCount"/>
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits[key]}" var="PUitem">
                                            <td style="{!IF(columnCount==ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap[key], 'border-right: 1px solid black;', '')}">
                                                <apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###,###.##}">
                                                    <apex:param value="{!item.pricesMap[key + ' ' + PUitem]}" />
                                                </apex:outputText>
                                            </td>
                                            <apex:variable value="{!columnCount+1}" var="columnCount" />
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                   <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Single_Reference__c,true,false)}">
                                        <td>{!item.totalsMap}</td>
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(MultiQuoteConfigurations.Single_Reference__c,false,true)}">
                                        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="columnCount2"/>
                                        <apex:repeat value="{!OverallListOfUnits}" var="unit">
                                            <td>{!item.referencesMap[unit]}</td>
                                          <apex:variable value="{!columnCount2+1}" var="columnCount2" />
                                        </apex:repeat>
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                </tr>
                                <apex:variable value="{!i+1}" var="i" />
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>

            <div class="bottom_section">
                <div>
                    By accepting this quote you accept Beacon's Terms of Service, which can be found on our website <a href="https://beacon.com/legal/terms-and-conditions">https://beacon.com/legal/terms-and-conditions</a><br/>
                    Please contact your Business Development representative or <a style="color: #ff7e23" href="mailto:support@beacon.co.uk">support@beacon.co.uk</a> for any enquiries about this quote.<br/>
                    More information can be provided for additional services such as invoice financing, purchase order financing, supply chain financing, and additional insurance.<br/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="terms_and_conditions">
                    Beacon Technologies Ltd. is a company registered in England and Wales. Company number 11664346 and VAT number 323 0540 51. Our registered mailing address is 42 Berkeley Square. London, W1J 5AW, United Kingdom.<br/>
                    <br/>
                        Terms and condition of quote<br/>
                        1) Unless otherwise specified above, this quote is subject to space and availability at time of booking and any relevant Peak Season Surcharges<br/>
                        2) This quote is subject to both Beacon and Shipping Line or Airline Standard Terms and Conditions<br/>
                        3) This quote is subject to changes in foreign exchange rates<br/>
                        4) Unless quoted above, this quote is subject to any applicable duties and taxes<br/>
                        5) Unless quoted above, this quote is subject to any other accessorial fees such as customs examinations or additional detention and demurrage<br/>
           
      
                </div>
            </div>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

```
public class MultiQuotePDFController {
    public Opportunity OpportunityRecord { get; private set; }
    public OpportunityLineItem OpportunityLineItem {get; private set; }
    public OpportunityLineItem OpportunityProducts {get; set;}
    public Map<String, Integer> ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap { get; private set; }
    public Map<String, String> ProductNameToCurrencyMap { get; private set; }
    public Integer NoOfUnitsForBeaconReference { get; private set; }
    public List<String> OverallListOfUnits { get; private set; }
    public List<Double> OverallTotals {get; private set;}
    Public List<String>OverallListOfCurrenciesAndUnits {get; private set;}
    Public List<String> quoteTotals {get; private set; }
    public Map<String, Set<String>> ProductNameToListOfUnits { get; private set; }
    public Map<String, Set<String>> CurrencytoPriceUnits { get; private set; }
    public List<OpportunityLineItem> OpportunityProductsList { get; private set; }
    public Multi_Quote_Groupings__mdt MultiQuoteConfigurations { get; private set; }
    public List<Item> ConvertedOpportunityProductsList { get; private set; }
    public Boolean IsError { get; private set; }
    public Map<String,List<Double>>QuoteCurrencyTotal {get; private set;}

    String OpportunityId = '';

    public MultiQuotePDFController() {
        IsError = false;
        OverallListOfUnits = new List<String>();
        ProductNameToListOfUnits = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
        OpportunityId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        OpportunityProductsList = getOpportunityLineItems(OpportunityId);
        OpportunityRecord = getOpportunityDate(OpportunityProductsList);
        MultiQuoteConfigurations = getMultiQuoteConfiguration(OpportunityRecord.Mode_of_Transport__c, OpportunityRecord.Shipment_Type__c);
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations != null) {
            populateRelatedData();
//
            List<AggregateResult> aggreageted_line_items = Database.query(queryConstructorAgg());
            ConvertedOpportunityProductsList = convertItems(aggreageted_line_items);
            

    private List<OpportunityLineItem> getOpportunityLineItems(String opportunity_id) {
        return
        [SELECT Beacon_Reference_Id__c, Price_Unit__c,Equipment_Type_Pull__c, Starting_Point_Seaport__r.Name,
                Ending_Point_Seaport__r.Name, Ending_Point_City__c, Ending_Point_Postcode__c, Ending_Point_Country__c,
                Starting_Point_City__c, Starting_Point_Postcode__c, Starting_Point_Country__c, Ending_Point_Airport__r.Name,
                Starting_Point_Airport__r.Name, Price_Currency__c,Cost_Currency__c, Product2.Name, Price_Amount__c,
                Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.Quoted_Date__c,unit_price__c,
                Opportunity.Mode_of_Transport__c, Opportunity.Shipment_Type__c, Opportunity.Quote_Expiration_Date__c,Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c,quote_currency__c
        FROM OpportunityLineItem
        WHERE OpportunityID = :opportunity_id
        ORDER BY Product2.Name, Equipment_Type_Lookup__c];
    }
    private Opportunity getOpportunityDate(List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunity_line_items) {
        if (!opportunity_line_items.isEmpty()) {
            OpportunityLineItem opportunity_line_item = opportunity_line_items.get(0);
            return opportunity_line_item.Opportunity;
        }
        return new Opportunity();
    }
    
    private Multi_Quote_Groupings__mdt getMultiQuoteConfiguration(String mode_of_transport, String shipment_type) {
        List<Multi_Quote_Groupings__mdt> configs = [SELECT Single_Reference__c, Mode_of_Transport__c, Shipment_Type__c, Display_Arr_Airport__c, Display_Delivery__c,
                Display_Dep_Airport__c, Display_POD__c, Display_POL__c, Display_Pickup__c, Group_by_Arr_Airport__c,
                Group_by_Delivery__c, Group_by_Dep_Airport__c, Group_by_POD__c, Group_by_POL__c, Group_by_Pickup__c
        FROM Multi_Quote_Groupings__mdt
        WHERE Mode_of_Transport__c =: mode_of_transport
            AND Shipment_Type__c =: shipment_type
        LIMIT 1];
        if (configs.isEmpty()) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Multi-Quote PDF is not available for this type of Opportunity'));
            return null;
        }
        return configs.get(0);
    }

    private void populateRelatedData() {
        ProductNameToListOfUnits = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
        CurrencytoPriceUnits = new map<String, set<String>>();
        ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        ProductNameToCurrencyMap = new Map<String, String>();
        String Quote_Currency;
        QuoteCurrencyTotal = new Map<String,List<Decimal>>();
        
     
        Set<String> units_set = new Set<String>();
        for (OpportunityLineItem opportunity_line_item : OpportunityProductsList) {
            String price_unit = (String.isNotBlank(opportunity_line_item.Equipment_Type_Pull__c)) ? opportunity_line_item.Equipment_Type_Pull__c : '-';
            units_set.add(price_unit);
            if (!ProductNameToListOfUnits.containsKey(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name)) {
                ProductNameToListOfUnits.put(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name, new Set<String>());
            }
            
            List<Decimal>unit_price_quote_currency_list = new List<Decimal>();
            for(OpportunityLineItem opportunityproducts: OpportunityProductsList){
            Double Quote_Unit_Price = (opportunityproducts.Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c !=null) ? opportunityproducts.Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c:null;
                

            ProductNameToListOfUnits.get(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name).add(price_unit);
            String cost_currency = String.isNotBlank(opportunity_line_item.Cost_Currency__c) ? opportunity_line_item.Cost_Currency__c : '-';
            ProductNameToCurrencyMap.put(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name, cost_currency);
        
        
        
        }
       
        OverallListOfUnits.addAll(units_set);
        NoOfUnitsForBeaconReference = OverallListOfUnits.size();

        for (String key : ProductNameToListOfUnits.keySet()) {
            ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap.put(key, ProductNameToListOfUnits.get(key).size());
        }
    }
    private String queryConstructorAgg() {
        String query_string = 'SELECT SUM (Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c) unitpricequotecurrency, ';
        List<String> query_fields = new List<String>();
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Arr_Airport__c) query_fields.add('Ending_Point_Airport__r.Name endingPointAirportName');
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Delivery__c) query_fields.add('Ending_Point_City__c, Ending_Point_Postcode__c, Ending_Point_Country__c');
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Dep_Airport__c) query_fields.add('Starting_Point_Airport__r.Name startingPointAirportName');
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Pickup__c) query_fields.add('Starting_Point_City__c, Starting_Point_Postcode__c, Starting_Point_Country__c');
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POD__c) query_fields.add('Ending_Point_Seaport__r.Name endingPointSeaportName');
        if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POL__c) query_fields.add('Starting_Point_Seaport__r.Name startingPointSeaportName');
      
        
        query_string += String.join(query_fields, ', ');
        query_string += ' FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID = :OpportunityId';

        query_string += ' GROUP BY  ';
     
       List<String> group_fields = new List<String>();
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Arr_Airport__c) group_fields.add('Ending_Point_Airport__r.Name');
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Delivery__c) group_fields.add('Ending_Point_City__c, Ending_Point_Postcode__c, Ending_Point_Country__c');
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Dep_Airport__c) group_fields.add('Starting_Point_Airport__r.Name');
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Pickup__c) group_fields.add('Starting_Point_City__c, Starting_Point_Postcode__c, Starting_Point_Country__c');
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POD__c) group_fields.add('Ending_Point_Seaport__r.Name');
       if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POL__c) group_fields.add('Starting_Point_Seaport__r.Name');
        
          
       query_string += String.join(group_fields, ', ');
        return query_string;
    }
    
    
    private List<Item> convertItems(List<AggregateResult> aggregate_line_items) {

        
   Map<String,Decimal> UnitsToTotal = new map <String,Decimal>();
        for (AggregateResult a :aggregate_line_items){
        }
        system.debug('UnitsToTotal' + UnitsToTotal);
            
        
        List<Item> line_items = new List<Item>();
        for (AggregateResult item : aggregate_line_items) {
            Item single_line_item = new Item();
            single_line_item.unitpricequotecurrency = (Double)item.get('unitpricequotecurrency');
            
                      
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POL__c) {
                single_line_item.Starting_Point_Seaport_Name = (String)item.get('startingPointSeaportName');
            }
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_POD__c) {
                single_line_item.Ending_Point_Seaport_Name = (String)item.get('endingPointSeaportName');

            }
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Dep_Airport__c) {
                single_line_item.Starting_Point_Airport_Name = (String)item.get('startingPointAirportName');


            }
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Arr_Airport__c) {
                single_line_item.Ending_Point_Airport_Name = (String)item.get('endingPointAirportName');
                
            }
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Delivery__c) {
                single_line_item.Ending_Point_City = (String)item.get('Ending_Point_City__c');
                single_line_item.Ending_Point_Postcode = (String)item.get('Ending_Point_Postcode__c');
                single_line_item.Ending_Point_Country = (String)item.get('Ending_Point_Country__c');
                populateDelivery(single_line_item);
            }
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Group_by_Pickup__c) {
                single_line_item.Starting_Point_City = (String)item.get('Starting_Point_City__c');
                single_line_item.Starting_Point_Postcode = (String)item.get('Starting_Point_Postcode__c');
                single_line_item.Starting_Point_Country = (String)item.get('Starting_Point_Country__c');
                populatePickup(single_line_item);

            }
            line_items.add(single_line_item);
        }
        return line_items;
   
    }
    private void populatePickup(Item single_line_item) {
        List<String> pickup_list = new List<String>();
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Starting_Point_City)) pickup_list.add(single_line_item.Starting_Point_City);
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Starting_Point_Postcode)) pickup_list.add(single_line_item.Starting_Point_Postcode);
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Starting_Point_Country)) pickup_list.add(single_line_item.Starting_Point_Country);
        single_line_item.Pickup = String.join(pickup_list, ', ');
    }

    private void populateDelivery(Item single_line_item) {
        List<String> delivery_list = new List<String>();
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Ending_Point_City)) delivery_list.add(single_line_item.Ending_Point_City);
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Ending_Point_Postcode)) delivery_list.add(single_line_item.Ending_Point_Postcode);
        if(String.isNotBlank(single_line_item.Ending_Point_Country)) delivery_list.add(single_line_item.Ending_Point_Country);
        single_line_item.Delivery = String.join(delivery_list, ', ');
    }

    public void getPricesAndReferences(List<Item> items) {
        for (Item i : items) {
            i.pricesMap = new Map<String, Double>();
            i.referencesMap = new Map<String, Double>();
            i.totalsMap = new Map <String,Double>();
            i.costCurrencyTotal = new map <String, Double>();
            i.unitsToTotal = new map <String, Double>();
          
           
            if (MultiQuoteConfigurations.Single_Reference__c) {
                NoOfUnitsForBeaconReference = 1;
                
 
            }
            for (OpportunityLineItem opportunity_line_item : OpportunityProductsList) {
                String price_unit = (String.isNotBlank(opportunity_line_item.Equipment_Type_Pull__c)) ? opportunity_line_item.Equipment_Type_Pull__c : '-';
                String cost_currency = (String.isNotBlank(opportunity_line_item.Cost_Currency__c)) ? opportunity_line_item.Cost_Currency__c : '-';
                if (i.isRelatedRecord(opportunity_line_item, MultiQuoteConfigurations)) {
                    Decimal baseTotal = (i.totalsMap.get(price_unit) == null) ? 0 : i.totalsMap.get(price_unit);
                    i.totalsMap.put(price_unit, baseTotal + opportunity_line_item.unit_price_quote_currency__c);
                    i.pricesMap.put(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name + ' ' + price_unit, opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price__c != null ? opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price__c : null);
                    i.referencesMap.put(price_unit, opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c !=null ? opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price_Quote_Currency__c : null);
                    
                    
                    i.costCurrencyTotal.put(cost_currency + ' ' + price_unit, opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price__c !=null ? opportunity_line_item.Unit_Price__c: null);
                    
                } else {
                    i.pricesMap.put(opportunity_line_item.Product2.Name + ' ' + price_unit, null);
                    i.referencesMap.put(price_unit, null);
                    i.totalsMap.put(price_unit,null);
                    i.costCurrencyTotal.put(cost_currency + ' ' + price_unit,null); 
                
                
                     
                    }              
                    
                    
                   }
                 }
              }
                        


    public class Item {
        Public String EquipmentType {get;set;}
        public Double unitpricequotecurrency {get;set;}
        public String Starting_Point_Seaport_Name {get;set;}
        public String Ending_Point_Seaport_Name {get;set;}
        public String Starting_Point_Airport_Name {get;set;}
        public String Ending_Point_Airport_Name {get;set;}
        public String Ending_Point_City {get;set;}
        public String Ending_Point_Postcode {get;set;}
        public String Ending_Point_Country {get;set;}
        public String Starting_Point_City {get;set;}
        public String Starting_Point_Postcode {get;set;}
        public String Starting_Point_Country {get;set;}
        public String Pickup {get;set;}
        public String Delivery {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal> pricesMap {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal> referencesMap {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal> totalsMap {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal>quoteCurrencyTotal {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal>costCurrencyTotal {get;set;}
        public Map<String, Decimal>currToTotalMap {get;set;}
        Public Decimal cost_currency {get; set;}
        public map<String, Decimal> UnitsToTotal {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely coming from one of these `apex:repeat` iterations:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!ProductNameToListOfUnits}" var="key">
    <th colspan="{!ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap[key]}" ...</th>
</apex:repeat>
```

so the problem lies in the Apex controller class `MultiQuotePDFController` where the `ProductNameToListOfUnits` collection ends up with a value in it that is not present as a key in the `ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap` map.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I have added the controller for clarification. I know its lengthy, but I am not able to see what I need to change.

Comment: Since you have the specific error value, you need to set some debug statements and review the debug log so you can see how you're populating your map, and why this value isn't in it.

Comment: This is my first time dealing with apex controllers. Where would I put the debug statements?

Comment: @AshK I would start by putting this and similar ones for other properties at the end of `populateRelatedData`: `System.debug('>>> ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap=\n' + JSON.serializePretty(ProductNameToNoOfPriceUnitsMap);`.

Comment: @KeithC I have added the statement as you suggested but now I am lost as to what to do next. I know I need to run a test, but what do I write?

Comment: Hi @AshK this site is designed for a single question and answer, not threads so no more comments from me.